# Multiple projects with separate Git repo dependent on each other: how to create local builds?

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, build

I have several projects (Commons, ProjectA, ProjectB) in IntelliJ that each reside in their own Git repo. ProjectA and ProjectB depend on project Commons. When I change code in Commons I have to build Commons in GitLab, load the new version through artifactory into Intellij. Otherwise ProjectA and ProjectB in IntelliJ won't see the changes made in Commons. Also, when being in ProjectA or ProjectB and jumping into code defined in Commons IntelliJ opens up the jar of Commons it retrieved from Artifactory and decompiles it on the fly.

Question: What do I need to do, that I can build changes in Commons **locally** so that they become visible for ProjectA and ProjectB? What do I need to do that I jump to the source code of Commons when jumping to code of Commons called in ProjectA or ProjectB?

Comment: Make a parent project with pom.xml defining the dependencies between these 3 projects. Import the root pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA. Your 3 projects will become modules in IntelliJ IDEA and the dependencies will be resolved via module sources instead of the repository artifacts.

Comment: @CrazyCode: Thanks for your comment. With the change to micro services in our system we abandonned the approach of using parent poms ...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to go through GitLab and Artifactory. If you build Commons with Maven on your local computer with version x.y.z-SNAPSHOT and reference it in ProjectA and ProjectB, they will pick up the changes automatically through the Maven local repository on your computer.

In Eclipse you could even open the three projects in the same workspace and all changes would be resolved automagically without running builds. But I do not know if IntelliJ offers something similar.

For the comment of CrazyCoder: You could put all three projects into one multi-module project but this is not a technical but an architecture decision. If you want to always build those three projects together with the same version number, use multi-module, otherwise not.

Comment: Problem is that the maven build puts the created jar into the project's target dir. But ProjectA/ProjectB picks the jar from the local maven repo into dir x.y.z-SNAPSHOT-<timestamp>

Comment: "In Eclipse you could even open the three projects in the same workspace and all changes would be resolved automagically without running builds. But I do not know if IntelliJ offers something similar." That's the point :-). Am looking for IntelliJ for the same thing as in eclipse.

Comment: " ... t but this is not a technical but an architecture decision". Yes, it's an architecture decision in my case from the architect ...

Comment: If you run `clean install` with Maven, the resulting jar will go to the local repository `.m2/repository` and is accessible by all other projects on the same computer.

Comment: The solution was to define the jar in the local maven repository using File > Project Structure > Modules